# Warning after installing pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am recently learning Python and package management. I already have some trouble with installing pip3. I followed these two webpages to install pip3 using command line:

1. [pip3 installation](https://vgkits.org/blog/pip3-config-howto/)
2. [pip3 configuration](https://vgkits.org/blog/pip3-macos-howto/)

And before the installation, when I typed `pip3 --version`, the output is:

```
pip 19.0.3 from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Then after the configuration, the output becomes:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
pip 20.2 from /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

I also checked `pip --version`, and the output is:

```
pip 20.2 from /Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Now I am not sure exactly what I can do to get rid of this warning other than use `python3 -m pip`. Is the website I followed somewhat faulty?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the GitHub link in the error message and other information, it appears that when you installed pip the PATH may not have been set correctly. Your first link for the pip3 installation did a `--user` install when the PATH may be trying to use the system version.

Your best shot would be to try to see if your PATH is set to the system wrapper and change it to match the `local user` wrapper.

Comment: Is there a way to check if my PATH is set to the system wrapper?

Comment: Assuming this is the issue: In order to change PATH, right-click "This PC" in file explorer, Properties --> Advanced system settings --> Environmental Variables. There you will see a User variables and System variables section, both will include PATH which you can edit & add a new path to make sure it's the system.